# Exclude javascript from being loaded for touch screen devices

Tags: javascript

I am using tinyscrollbar to replace the standard scrollbars on desktop versions of my web app. The main reason for this is so that i have a consistent and nice design across all desktop browsers. On an android, mobile ios device and windows mobile device i would just want to use the native scroller. This means that i wouldnt want to include my scroller css nor the javascript for it. If anyone has any experience with this it would be very helpful. I worry about windows 8 machines becuase they are desktops and tablets.

Comment: Detect if device supports touch?

Comment: How will you deal with devices that support both?

Comment: "so that i have a consistent and nice design across all desktop browsers" Why do you break the UI for some just so you can feel clever? Users couldn't care less about other browsers, they typically only use one browser and would like it to work as they expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for conditionnal loading, I suggest [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/), it is the script loader used in [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load) (so if you use Modernizr, it's probably already there).

```
Modernizr.load({
  test : Modernizr.touch,
  nope : 'slick-scroller.js'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not use modernizr currently but it look like that would do the job